# Admob android cannot change from banner INVISIBLE to VISIBLE

Tags: android, admob

How do you people use admob banner? Can you please take a look at my code and show what is wrong with it. I have a game that has a Pause screen and it has much room to place a banner.

However when I load it, banner takes too long to show up in slow connection. So i made to load it up but keep it INVISIBLE, then make it visible when I need it. But it's not work. The banner won't visible! Please give me any advice...
Here is the code:

```
//Admob request Banner
bannerAdmob = new AdView(this);
bannerAdmob.setAdSize(AdSize.WIDE_SKYSCRAPER);
bannerAdmob.setAdUnitId(Setting.admobBannerId);
requestAdmobBanner();
```

I use handler to choose adunit. Interstitial is work nice, but neither banner.

```
protected Handler handlerAdmob = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1: //If is interstitial
            if (interstitialAdmob.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAdmob.show();
            } else {                        
                requestAdmobInterstitial();
            }
            break;
        case 2: //If is banner
            bannerAdmob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 6: //Hide banner
            bannerAdmob.destroy();
            requestAdmobBanner(); //Request new banner
        }
    }
};
```

Then the method to load banner

```
private void requestAdmobBanner() {
    AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice(Setting.Device_ID)
    .build();

    // Load the banner ad.
    bannerAdmob.loadAd(bannerRequest);

    // Now we add ads listener for Admob banner so we can SHOW and HIDE it
    bannerAdmob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) { // On admob interstitial failed to load, request new ad
            bannerAdmob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            bannerAdmob.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            System.out.println("Banner Admob is load, but still INVISIBLE");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the AdView to be **INVISIBLE**, when you should be setting it to **VISIBLE**. See code below:

```
// Now we add ads listener for Admob banner so we can SHOW and HIDE it
bannerAdmob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) { // On admob interstitial failed to load, request new ad
        bannerAdmob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        bannerAdmob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("#onAdLoaded - making AdView visible");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes
Just like my statement above, I load banner and keep it INVISIBLE. Then make it VISIBLE in pause screen at no time. You know admob didn't have any preload method for banner. I want to to show banner ad in no delay even at slow connection.

Comment: No, you are making the banner INVISIBLE when the ad is loaded.

Comment: @William setAdListener is not working when adview.destory is been called, can you please help me ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the AdListener to be called after the View it is listening to has been destroyed.